# Strange Behavior in Pyplot Quiver Function

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, visualization

I have a very simple cell of code that draws a single vector with `pyplot.quiver`. It should start at `(0,0)` and stretch to `(1,1)`. However, the arrow is clearly not directed to `(1,1)`.

The documentation says that, with the call signature:

> quiver([X, Y], U, V, [C], **kw)
>
> X, Y define the arrow locations, U, V define the arrow directions, and
> C optionally sets the color.

What is happening here?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.quiver(0,0,1,1, scale=5)
plt.xlim(-2, 2)
plt.ylim(-2, 2)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.quiver.Quiver.html), you should specify `angles`, `scale_units` and `scale` parameters in order to tell matplotlib you want to refer to (x, y) coordinates and units:

```
ax.quiver(0, 0, 1, 1, angles = 'xy', scale_units = 'xy', scale = 1)
```

[image]